# Conflicting 'this' in jQuery plugin with 'this' from event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to work with the `this` keyword in the following jQuery plugin, however I don't want to access the `this` of the click event, but the `this` of the plugin.

How do I do that? currently I get the following error in the Plugin.prototype.toggleTranslationMode function:

> Cannot read property 'enableTranslationMode' of undefined

```js
;
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
  var pluginName = 'translationMode',
    defaults = {
      //marker: "value"
    };

  function Plugin(element, options) {
    this.element = $(element);
    this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
  }

  Plugin.prototype.init = function() {
    this.getTranslationData();
    this.createMarkup();
    this.addEvents();
  };

  Plugin.prototype.getTranslationData = function() {
    this.elementIndex = this.element.data('element-index');
    this.translationIndex = this.element.data('translation-index');
    this.original = this.element.data('translation-original');
    this.translation = this.element.data('translation-trans');
    this.translationType = this.element.data('translation-type');
  }

  Plugin.prototype.createMarkup = function() {
    this.element.addClass('translation-container');
    this.element.wrapInner('<span class="editor"></span>');
    this.editor = this.element.find('.editor');
    this.addMarker();
  }

  Plugin.prototype.addMarker = function() {
    this.element.append('<div class="translation-marker">' + this.elementIndex + '-' + this.translationIndex + '</div>');
    this.marker = this.element.find('.translation-marker');
  };

  Plugin.prototype.enableTranslationMode = function() {
    console.log('translation mode enabled')
    this.element.addClass('translation-modal-visible');
    this.element.append('<div class="translation-modal">Original String:' + original + '</div>');
  }

  Plugin.prototype.disableTranslationMode = function() {
    console.log('translation mode disabled')
    this.element.removeClass('translation-modal-visible');
    this.element.find('.translation-modal').remove();
  }

  Plugin.prototype.addEvents = function() {
    this.disableLinksAndButtons();
    this.toggleTranslationMode();
  }

  /*
   * EVENTS
   */

  Plugin.prototype.toggleTranslationMode = function() {
    this.element.on('click', this.marker, function(e) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('translation-modal-visible')) {
        this.disableTranslationMode();
      } else {
        this.enableTranslationMode();
      }
    })
  }

  Plugin.prototype.disableLinksAndButtons = function() {
    $("a, button").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }

  $.fn[pluginName] = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
        $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName,
          new Plugin(this, options));
      }
    });
  }
})(jQuery, window, document);

jQuery(function($) {
  $('[data-translation-index]').translationMode();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside event handler belongs to the element on which the event is called. You are trying to access `this.element. enableTranslationMode` inside your click event handler and expect it to be the same as outside(the prototype function scope). This will not be the case.

You can save the outside this as another variable and access it inside. But in your case I think you can directly access `this.enableTranslitionMode` since you are looking for the element itself.